# Isn't it more clear to say "View votes to close" than the current "View close votes"?

Tags: feature-request

First, the word "close" can have a few very distinct meanings, some being:

- "to come to an end or terminate" such as, Close the door [or close this question].
- "having the parts or elements near to one another" such as, The candidates are in a close race.  (I'm trying to keep close to the voting paradigm -- haha)

(Definitions taken from [Dictionary.com definition of close](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/close))

And, when I first saw on SO/SE "View close votes" I read it as the second, but I couldn't understand what that meant. (me: "Close? Close to what?") To those of us who don't (or didn't) know that there was a voting process to close out a question, it's easily misunderstood.

Don't you think the phrase should be rewritten to say, "View votes to close" instead of "View close votes" because it would be more clearly understood?

Here is a screen shot of the listing of Privileges. It's the primary place where the phrase is shown.

[image: Privileges, shows "view close votes"]

Comment: Where is "View close votes?" I don't recall seeing that action anywhere.

Comment: @DG, I added a screen shot that shows the phrase.

Comment: Click on your reputation number to see the chart listed above